# Structuring java Class UMLs Correctly

Tags: java, class, class-design

can someone explain to me how would I correctly structure these classes I have made an attempt but am not sure if they are correct.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6x3N.jpg - UML
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCCzw.jpg - Dataset

A. List all crime types (by name) for which you have data.
B. For a given crime type and LSOA, display details of all crimes, for which you have data.
C. For a given LSOA, determine how many crimes are presently

1. “Under investigation”
2. “Investigation complete; no suspect identified” for a given month
   D. Find the LSOA with the highest average total crime frequency
   E. Find the LSOA with the highest average frequency of crimes under investigation.
   F. For a given crime, find which LSOA has the most occurrences.

Comment: Hi Niklaus, please could you edit your post to include the specification of the classes (ie what they need to contain) so I can check it for you.

Comment: I need to upload a CSV file into a array list and pull data from it with approapreate search function. Yet I'm confused were to start.

Comment: You've just listed your coursework assignment. Please state what the classes requirements are e.g. Class person contains a string called firstName etc.
Please also see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help format your question in a better way.

Comment: I have no class specifications, I have to analyse dataset and create basic classes, I'm confused how to do that! And if the ones I have created are correct!

Comment: Okay great, please can you give an example or snippet of the dataset?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/slb80uR , sorry if am not making any sence I'm generally confused.

Comment: No this makes sense now thank you, I'm assuming you have a Crime class and a CrimeManager class? The Crime class contains all the things from the dataset and the CrimeManager class contains the functions to search crimes, list all crimes etc. Is this correct?

Comment: I have created a class UML that represents the data set called StreetData and a user interface class that would speficy the functions! So the stuff I made, is that correct or have I missunderstood it.

Answer (score 0):

Your UML for the first class is great, although if all the strings for a property are repeated or from a certain list, I'd recommend looking into [Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

The second class is also along the right lines but I've made an example one: [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56XKX.jpg) which you can add to/rename slightly to better fit your requirements.